# Open a new page using HTML Response/JS ASP

Tags: asp.net

Alright, I have decided to go about this by opening a new page (newPage.aspx) which will then initiate the download and close after the download is completed. I am opening newPage.aspx using javascript by writing it to the response of the current page. For some reason, however, the window is not being opened before the original page is re-directed. Is their a method to be called before I redirect? Maybe I have a syntax issue?

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('~/newPage.aspx', '', ''); </script>")

Response.Redirect("~/oldPage.aspx")
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the following but it did not work... (I am working in an Update Panel)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(udpMain, udpMain.GetType(), "openExcel", "window.open('~/newPage.aspx', '' , '');", True)
```

**EDIT 2: So Close**

Ok, so this only works if I comment out the Response.Redirect. It seems that the RegisterStartupScript method takes place on the page load after the Response.Redirect method. Is there any known fix for this?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(udpMain, udpMain.GetType(), "openExcel", "window.open(NewPage.aspx'); location.href='OldPage.aspx';", True)
Response.Redirect("~/OldPage.aspx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect via client script as well. By the way when using ASP.NET preferable way of embedding JS into HTML is `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` e.g

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "JSCode" & Rnd(1).ToString, "window.open('newPage.aspx'); location.href = 'oldPage.aspx'", True)
```

Comment: See edit in OP... maybe you can find a syntax error? I ran it and stepped over the function, without error, but also without a new window opening.

Comment: `Response.Write` will definetely not work inside of UpdatePanel, while properly formatted `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` should. Try following: 

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(udpMain.Page, udpMain.Page.GetType(), "openExcel", "window.open('newPage.aspx');location.href='oldPage.aspx';", True)`

Comment: Do not use `Response.Redirect` - it does not work inside of UpdatePanel either. `location.href` inside of client script should take care of redirect.